# Change page orientation using Infragistics

Tags: pdf, orientation, infragistics

I am trying to change my export pdf orientation (using Infragistics), i used this code :

```
report = new Report();
section = report.AddSection();
section.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
section.PageMargins.All = 20;
```

but nothing happened.

can you help, please ?

Answer (score 1):

You ned to set page width and height to match the landscape ones. [Here](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/52400.aspx) the guys from Infragistics shown how to do this. Here is and the code they suggested:

```
section1.PageSize = New PageSize(Infragistics.Documents.Report.PageSizes.A4.Height, Infragistics.Documents.Report.PageSizes.A4.Width
```